# Javascript - replace multiple characters and spaces in a string

Tags: javascript

There are multiple solutions on StackOverflow to repace multiple characters in a string and from that I have this code:

```
var replaceChars = { ' ':'-', 'ń':'n', 'ó':'o', 'ż':'z', 'ą':'a' };
var answerStrUrl = answerStr.replace(/ń|ó|ż|ą/g,function(match) {return replaceChars[match];}).toLowerCase();
```

(answerStrUrl is defined earlier in the code)

This works for all the characters but what should I add in the second line so that spaces are replaced with '-'

Comment: If you want to match all whitespace (including tabs and newlines), use a `\s`. If you only want to match spaces, use a " " (literal space character)

Comment: In case the OP's effort is all about unifying/normalizing strings in order to later compare them one to another, there are e.g. the [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator) as well as the prototypal [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) `String` method which both are specialized in handling this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `|\s+|` in the replace function.

```
var answerStrUrl = answerStr.replace(/ń|ó|ż|\s+|ą/g,function(match) {return replaceChars[match];}).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Build the regexp dynamically and use `[]` character group:

```js
const replaceChars = { ' ':'-', 'ń':'n', 'ó':'o', 'ż':'z', 'ą':'a' };

const answerStr = 'ń ń ń ń ń';
const regex = new RegExp(`[${Object.keys(replaceChars).join('')}]`, 'g');
const answerStrUrl = answerStr.replace(regex, m => replaceChars[m]).toLowerCase(); 
console.log(answerStrUrl);
```